# PHP - AS400 DB2 table uses $ at the start of the field name

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm joining a code description table to the table that has the code. Each field in the code description table starts with a $. PHP thinks these are variables and breaks. Is there a way to tell PHP these are field names and not variables?

Thank you

```
select $text FROM l0text where $code = 'XLST' and $value = c2xlst
```

Comment: I think you are still missing a detail to make this question and it's answer understandable. What is the full line of code that includes the SQL select statement? is it something like `stmt = "select $text FROM l0text where $code = 'XLST' and $value = c2xlst";`? Please include the entire statement, not just a snippet. The problem might be somewhere you didn't expect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
$text = '$text';
$code = '$code';
$value = '$value';
```

By making variables with the same field name it allowed the sql to run correctly.

Comment: I think this solution might leave you open to SQL injection somehow. Please follow my comments above to edit your question. You will then get a better answer, maybe even with an explanation of the behavior.